# Detect line breaks in MySQL?

Tags: html, mysql, sql, replace, line-breaks

I've been searching for hours now but can't find anything that actually works.

I've got this in multiple records :

```
<p style="text-align: justify;"> SOME TEXT </p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"> MORE TEXT </p>
```

I want to change it to this :

```
<p style="text-align: justify;"> SOME TEXT 
MORE TEXT </p>
```

I want to keep the line break but delete the first end tag and the second start tag.

I tried this :

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_collumn = REPLACE(my_collumn,'</p> <p style="text-align: justify;">','')
```

BUT it doesn't detect it because of the LINE BREAK between it.

How can I solve this?

Many thanks

Comment: The first snapshot where you show two lines, it that stored in a SINGLE MySql record ?

Comment: Yes, it's always in a single record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, you'd probably be better off doing this sort of replacement in your language of choice, which will offer stronger string handling capabilities than MySQL. That said, MySQL recognizes several C-style [character escapes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) in strings, including both `\r` and `\n`; a CRLF in a MySQL string is therefore just `'\r\n'`.

Comment: Thank you for your answser.

When I search for '\r\n', it finds loads of occurrences.

But if I add </p> or <p style="text-align: justify;">

It doesn't find anything anymore. Any idea why ?

</p>\r\n<p style="text-align: justify;">

Comment: There may be spaces on either side of the newline, or something else non-obvious -- that's why I suggest, if possible, doing this kind of transform in code, instead of query, and preferably in a language offering strong regular expression support.

Comment: @itachi42 If you can, do it in code, as DanFromGermany has also suggested -- otherwise, I'm not really sure what to suggest, save 'try, try again'.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you not to use MySQL for the string operations. This is not what a Database is made for. Use PHP, Perl, ASP, whatever you are coding with.

Problems you might run into:

Instead of common line break `\r\n` between the tags, you might have to parse different cases:

```
<blankspace>\r\n
\n\n
\n
\r\n<blankspace>\r\n
...
```

someday, you also might want to change

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">
```

to

```
<p class="textClass">
```

Then you'd need to change the SQL again.

If you really wonna do it, have a look at UDFs like

[Regex Replace in MySQL](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme)

Comment: I'm storing all the content into databases so I can change the whole HTML layout ;) so yeah, I'm planning to use CSS

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use `char(13) + char(10)` to include a newline:

```
'</p>' + char(13) + char(10) + '<p ...>'
```

The meaning of the numbers can be found in the [ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/):

```
13 = carriage return
10 = newline
```

Comment: I'm looking for the same in MySQL... :/

Comment: Have you looked at the MySQL documentation of string functions? There are analogs to everything in his answer.

Comment: In fact, it has `CHAR()`, so the only difference is that you use `CONCAT()` to concatenate strings instead of the `+` operator.

Comment: For MySQL, check out Aaron Miller's answer.